# No module named 'django' in conda virtualenv

Tags: django

I hadnt any python installed globally,just miniconda. Then created a virtualenv(conda) and installed django there. Now when I do "**django-admin.py startproject projectname**" (anaconda prompt,under created virtualenv) first it asked how to open that file & I set it to default python of miniconda ("C:\Users\1\Miniconda3\python.exe").Then it shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\1\Miniconda3\envs\Work_manager\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.core import management
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

sys.path of that virtualenv:

```
['', 'C:\\Users\\1\\Miniconda3\\envs\\Work_manager\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\1\\Miniconda3\\envs\\Work_manager\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\1\\Miniconda3\\envs\\Work_manager\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\1\\Miniconda3\\envs\\Work_manager',
 'C:\\Users\\1\\Miniconda3\\envs\\Work_manager\\lib\\site-packages']
```

django-admin.py is located at "C:\Users\1\Miniconda3\envs\Work_manager\Scripts" &
its shebang is "#!C:/Users/1/Miniconda3/envs/Work_manager\python.exe".

Im using windows 10(x64).

Comment: Did you install `django` in your virtual environment?

Comment: I think so. From conda prompt, $activate env $conda install django $pip install django (did both) $python >>>import django >>>django.VERSION -> shows version. So django is installed in that environment,right?